# Йотированный звук "И" (по статье Копелиовича)

Tags: фонетика

Какие звуки или какой звук  обозначает буква "и" в слове "мои"? В статье  А. Б. Копелиовича ["Правило йотированный буквы при морфемном анализе"](http://rus.1september.ru/view_article.php?ID=200900303) я прочитала, что звук "й" здесь присутствует, но не произносится, так как однокоренное слово заканчивается на "й" (мой). Предлагается сравнить с другими непроизносимыми буквами в словах, например в слове "солнце".

Comment: *В одной статье я прочитала, что звук "й" здесь присутствует, но не произносится* - это как? Звук - он как мед. Или он есть или его нету. И если уж такая пьянка пошла, давайте ссылку на источник.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, в принципе, сказано в прошлый раз. 
Такое сочетание можно прочитать как [мои], можно как [мойи] - на слух разницу уловить очень трудно, и то и другое можно считать вариантами одной нормы. Есть ли там этот йот - вопрос чисто академический и академики решают его по-разному.

//==========

Прочитал я статью, не очень углублялся, но идею схватил.
Конечно же, это статья "в порядке обсуждения". Никак не могу согласиться со столь радикальным изменением подхода к учению о фонетике. 
Согласно автору, пусть это нигде явно и не сказано, фонетика зависит от морфологии слова. Так, по Копелиовичу получается, что случаи **[уи]** в словах **буи** (мн. к буй) и **Луи** (имя собственное)  - фонетически разные, в первом присутствует-де непроизносимая фонема **Йот** - а во втором нет.

Непонятно не только, как это всё уложить в голове бедного школьника, не понятно, *зачем* оно вообще надо.

Впрочем, я не специалист. Подождем прочих мнений.

Comment: Я отредактировала вопрос и указала там название статьи

Comment: Вижу. Ну в таком случае, это мнение автора, имя которое мне ничего не говорит. Скорее всего статься - дискуссионная, ибо насколько знаю, "академики" не пришли пока к единому мнению - и нам, многогрешным, быть арбитрами в их споре не стоит. )))

Comment: А вот что касается формулировке "присутствует, но не произносится", то она мне резко не нравится. Тарабарщина, как минимум - неряшливость. [Звук]  *присутcтвует* и *произносится* - синонимы. Если звук "присутствует," то это значит "произносится".

Comment: Согласна с Вашим мнение , мне тоже показалась странной формулировка присутствия непроизносимого звука "й", поэтому было интересно мнение специалистов.

Comment: Ну подождем, здесь есть преподаватели, может они прольют свет на проблему. В крайнем случае могу уточнить на филфаке МГУ, что это, самодеятельность или .веяние  моды.

Comment: Было бы очень интересно.

Comment: Ну это - если сами не разберемся. ))) Надо ж  еще понять, как вопрос сформулировать )))